# Функция должна вернуть массив всех значений свойства с одинаковым именем из каждого объекта в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, объекты

Функция должна вернуть массив всех значений свойства с таким именем из каждого объекта в массиве products. Что то напутал в цикле for...of. Выводится только пустой массив.

```js
const products = [{
    name: "Radar",
    price: 1300,
    quantity: 4
  },
  {
    name: "Scanner",
    price: 2700,
    quantity: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Droid",
    price: 400,
    quantity: 7
  },
  {
    name: "Grip",
    price: 1200,
    quantity: 9
  },
];

function getAllPropValues(propName) {

  let arrValue = [];

  for (const product of products) {
    if (propName === product.propName) {
      return arrValue.push(propName);
    }
  }
  return arrValue;
}
```

Comment: `return arrValue.push(propName);` что это?

Comment: хочу запушить в масиив значения свойств со всех объектов

Comment: а return зачем?

Comment: Вывести его из функции

Comment: а тогда `return arrValue;` вот это что делает?

Comment: Если условие в if не выполниться, то выведет пустой массив. Что он и делает. А условие не работает

Answer (score 1):

Если я всё правильно понял, то вам просто нужно использовать метод [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) и не нужно никаких проверок:

```js
const products = [{
    name: "Radar",
    price: 1300,
    quantity: 4
  },
  {
    name: "Scanner",
    price: 2700,
    quantity: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Droid",
    price: 400,
    quantity: 7
  },
  {
    name: "Grip",
    price: 1200,
    quantity: 9
  },
];

const getAllPropValues = (propName) => products.map(product => product[propName]);

console.log(getAllPropValues('name'));
console.log(getAllPropValues('price'));
console.log(getAllPropValues('quantity'));
```

P.S. Если указанного свойства не будет в объекте, то вставится `undefined` в массив

Answer (score -1):

> if (propName === product.propName)

так не получится, так как в `product.propName` будет `undefined`. Даже если так `product[propName]` вы получите значение, а не сам ключ по которому сравниваете

вот такое решение в лоб:

```js
const products = [{
    name: "Radar",
    price: 1300,
    quantity: 4
  },
  {
    name: "Scanner",
    price: 2700,
    quantity: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Droid",
    price: 400,
    quantity: 7
  },
  {
    name: "Grip",
    price: 1200,
    quantity: 9
  },
];

console.log(getAllPropValues('name'))

function getAllPropValues(propName) {

  let arrValue = [];

  for (const product of products) {

    for (const obj in product) {
      if (obj == propName) {
        arrValue.push(product[obj])
      }
    }

  }
  return arrValue
}
```

Или такой вариант (без вложенного перебора):

```js
const products = [{
    name: "Radar",
    price: 1300,
    quantity: 4
  },
  {
    name: "Scanner",
    price: 2700,
    quantity: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Droid",
    price: 400,
    quantity: 7
  },
  {
    name: "Grip",
    price: 1200,
    quantity: 9
  },
];


console.log(getAllPropValues2('price'))

function getAllPropValues2(propName) {
  let a = []
  for (const product of products) {
    if (Object.keys(product).includes(propName)) {
      a.push(product[propName])
    }
  }
  return a
}
```